# Powershell Set ManagedPipeline for all Application Pools

Tags: powershell, iis-7

I've got a command that can list all app pools on a machine:

```
 Get-WmiObject -namespace "root/MicrosoftIISv2" -class IIsApplicationPool |Select-Object -property @{N="Name";E={$name = $_.Name; $name.Split("/")[2] }} | Format-Table
```

I want to set the managedpipeline of every app pool on the box. I've tried this:

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace "root/MicrosoftIISv2" -class IIsApplicationPool |Select-Object -property @{N="Name";E={$name = $_.Name; $name.Split("/")[2] }} | ForEach-Object {cmd /c "c:\windows\system32\inetsvr\appcmd.exe set apppool $name /managedPipleineMode:"Classic"'}
```

This is giving me a "cannot find the path specified" error. Any ideas how I can this to work?

Answer (score 8):

In order to set the Managed Pipeline mode (or any property of the AppPool), you need to use Set-ItemProperty.  But it gets more fun than that:

1. Set-ItemProperty takes a Path as its input.  Get-ChildItem will
   return you a collection of `ConfigurationElement` objects, not Path
   strings.
2. ManagedPipelineMode is internally stored as an integer, so
   you have to know the correct "magic" number to pass in.
   Fortunately, that is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690608), in the "Remarks" section.

This did the trick for me:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSPath |
    ForEach-Object { Set-ItemProperty $_ ManagedPipelineMode 1 }
```

EDIT: For posterity, here are the "magic" numbers defined from that link.  The default is 0 (`Integrated`).

| Value | Keyword | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Integrated | The managed pipeline runs in Integrated mode. |
| 1 | Classic | The managed pipeline runs in ISAPI mode. |

Comment: Just to add here, as mentioned by JamesQMurphy, the magic int for the ManagedPipelineMode is only documented in the Remarks Section of that article.



`0 Integrated The managed pipeline runs in Integrated mode.`
`1 Classic The managed pipeline runs in ISAPI mode.`

Comment: @JohnYoungtree Thanks, and good point... I've updated my answer (almost 10 years later!) to include the magic int values.  Gave me a chance to insert a table... I've never done that ;)

Answer (score 2):

following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-making-simple-configuration-changes-to-web-sites-and-application-pools#changing-site-and-apppool-settings) :

```
$iisAppPoolName = "MyPool"
$appPool = New-WebAppPool -Name $iisAppPoolName  
$appPool.managedPipelineMode = "Classic"
$appPool |Set-Item
```

I tested, IIS 8.0, Windows server 2012, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Powershell V2 I would use the WebAdministration module e.g. from an elevated prompt:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Foreach {$_.ManagedPipelineMode = 'Classic'}
```

Comment: Weird, I would think this would work but it's not. I've even run as administrator and it's not working. Not erroring, either.

Comment: No errors being shown. I can view the apppools fine (take away foreach) but with foreach .... it's not showing any output or changing the value. Would I have to restart the app pool?

Comment: even in powershell v4.0